# Transformation of r.v. with floor function

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, exponential-function, ceiling-and-floor-functions

$$X\in \text{Exp}(1),\quad Y\in [X]$$ Find the distribution of $Y$. This is what I have done ($f(x)$ is the distribution of $X$) $$P(Y=k)=P([X]=k)=P(k\leq X< (k+1))=\int_{k}^{k+1} f(x) dx=\int_{k}^{k+1}e^{-x}dx
=\Big[-e^{-x}\Big]_{k}^{k+1}=-e^{-(k+1)}-(-e^{-k})=e^{-k}(1-e^{-1})$$
$$Y\in Ge(1-e^{-1})$$
But now I have learned that the answer should be $Y\in Ge(1-e^{\frac{-1}{a}})$. What is correct?

Comment: Your solution is correct. What is $a$ ?!

Comment: I assume that it should be a constant. But now I know that it was wrong in the stated question (I think they meant that X has distribution Exp(1/a)), not in my answer. Thank you!